# convert date/time milliseconds Android

Tags: android, json, date

i am receiving a json data containing date values as show below

```
{"EndDate":"\/Date(1446912155713+0300)\/","CreatedOn":"\/Date(1446908555777+0300)\/","user":"user1"}
```

I am subtracting the CreatedOn date with EndDate date to get the number of minutes. before doing the subtraction i am converting the dates like this for example.

```
System.out.println(convertDate("1446912155713+0300", "hh:mm:ss"));
public static String convertDate(String dateInMilliseconds,String dateFormat) {
return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds)).toString();
}
```

And i get this below error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid long: "1446908555777+0300"
```

This is the format i receive it from json as show above: `"\/Date(1446912155713+0300)\/"`

Comment: if you try to convert a string "100+2" to double it will give not you `NumberFormatException` as it not a valid number due to the fact that there is "+" sign in the string which is not a number. The "+0300" is for time-zone I guess

Answer (score 1):

As the length of the milliseconds will remain the same for at least next 3 centuries,you can milliseconds from the `String` you can do the following.

```
String date = "1446908555777+0300";

date = date.substring(0, 12); //0 => start; 12=>last index of valid millisecond

System.out.println(convertDate(date, "hh:mm:ss")); 
public static String convertDate(String dateInMilliseconds,String dateFormat) {
return DateFormat.format(dateFormat, Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds)).toString();
}
```

Comment: what time you get after conversion?

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that the JSON you are receiving is not a valid `Long` value.

Your method `convertDate` expects a `Long` as it's first parameter, and you allow a `String` to be passed into it, but then use this in the method body:

```
Long.parseLong(dateInMilliseconds)
```

You can't parse a `String` into a `Long` when it has a "+" in it. That is not a numeric value (it is an operator).

You first need to convert the `String` value "Date(1446912155713+0300)" into a valid `Long` format. In particular, you need to either drop the "+0300" or use it in some meaningful way before you attempt to convert it to a `Long`. The answer already posted presumes that this is a timezone adjustment.